# Django - 2app 2 views 2 templates in one page

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to get into django dev but i am quite a newbie to this...
Here is my problem:

I have :

- App1 - for handling my site publication
- View 1
- Template 1 managing view1: index.html
- App2 named member - for managing users
- View 2
- Template 2 managing view2: login.html

basically, the 1 group is my main page and the 2 group is a user login form.
I'd like to embed my login form in a right menu on the site main page like we can see on many sites.

- View 1 / templates 1 extends my content block from base.html

  ```
  def MainHomePage(request):
  homepage = HomePage.objects.get(pk=1)
  context = {'homepage': homepage}
  return render_to_response('index.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
  ```
- View 2 / templates 2 extends my right_menu from base.html with my login form

  ```
  def LoginRequest(request):
  if request.user.is_authenticated():
      return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
      if request.method =='POST':
      form =LoginForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
          username = form.cleaned_data['username']
          password = form.cleaned_data['password']
          member = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
          if member is not None:
              login(request, member)
              return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
          else:
              return render_to_response('login.html', {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
         else:
              return render_to_response('login.html', {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
  else:
      form = LoginForm()
      context = {'form':form}
      return render_to_response('login.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
  ```

I don't see how to do that!
I think maybe i should import the view2 in view1 and return a proper response for both
what about the templates should they be merged too?
can't see how as they are called by 2 difference urls. well i'm a bit lost
I 'll be glad if anyone could enlighten my mind...

Comment: Is your code for `LoginRequest` fine? Seems you have extra indentation after the `return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')` line.

Comment: sorry bad copy paste, it's fin in my views.py file.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your login view, it doesn't seem to be doing anything that you require something like embedding `LoginRequest` view. Instead, you can just pass the form as context to the main page template, display it where you want and change the action of that `form` to the URL that is handled by `LoginRequest`. This way, `LoginRequest` view will behave just like it would when logging from login.html

Comment: Many thanks for your answer.
To clearly understand, i should pass 2 context to the main page
the "Homepage" and the one for the login form and when submitting a login request it should aim to login view and template, whose will handle the login connection and redirect to page i want.

Answer (score -1):

your [templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/#templates) would actually do the "pointing".  For example, a user would land at MainHomePage, which is basically the index.html template.  Inside that template, you would have the login form defined. The Login form's action could point to the LoginRequest view.

I would like to point out that you don't need to have a separate app to manage users. This can be done by [using/extending Django's admin site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#module-django.contrib.admin).

Also, you should consider going through their [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/), since it covers what you're trying to do and walks through much of the core functionality.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Many thanks too for your answer!
i will look into your links, i already took the django tutorial a while ago but maybe i miss some parts now...
For information, i followed the tutorials at hackedexistence.com